Evaluating $\lim_{x\to 0}\;(x^2+1)^{(\cos(x)-1)^{-1}}$
I can't find the answer to this limit:
$$\lim_{x\to 0}\;\left(x^2+1\right)^{(\cos(x)-1)^{-1}}$$
When I put this limit in online calculators I find two answers: $0.1353352832366$ or 'indeterminate'

You can take logarithm, and try L'Hospital principle.

$\cos x - 1\approx -\frac12x^2$, so $(\cos x - 1)^{-1}\approx -\frac{2}{x^2}$.
So we want $\lim_{x\to 0}(1+x^2)^{-2/x^2}$, which is $$\lim_{y\to 0^+}(1+y)^{-2/y}=1/\left(\lim_{y\to0+}(1+y)^{1/y}\right)^2=1/e^2\approx 0.1353352832366$$
